# Is there a way to reduce the risk of a disaster?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In patch 1.9, [disasters](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Disasters) were introduced to replace the earlier random system of bad things happening.

Now you can see exactly what conditions in your nations raise the progress to a disaster happening to what monthly degree.

For example if you are not in a war and have low manpower, you will get a monthly increase towards a peasant war between +0.5% and +2%.

When you go to war again or raise your manpower, the progress towards the disaster stops increasing, but does not go away.

**Is there any way to cancel the progress altogether or at least reduce it again?**

Otherwise it seems that sooner or later the disaster is going to happen, because over a long time period you will always have a short period of the disaster conditions being met and this will keep raising the progress slowly but steadily.

Comment: Eh? Doesn't it decline or go away? It does in my game. E.g., I had an upcoming religious uprising, which went away when I had all my provinces converted to the True Faith™.

Comment: Well, that's what I am asking. :) Does it go away, and how? In my Ottoman game I can't get rid of the Peasant war bar, even though it has not risen in years. but maybe I need to meet some criteria to make it disappear.

Answer (score 3):

The disasters are well documented in the EU4 wiki.

To take your peasants war as an example, here's how it should work:

> **Pre-requisites**
>   - Is a monarchy (except Celestial Empire and Steppe Horde).
>   - Has greater than 5 provinces.
>   **Progress**
>    - Has no disaster ongoing.
>    - Manpower less than 25.0%.
>   **Monthly Progress**
>   0.5% when: not at war, overextension between 25% and 50%
>   1.0% when: not at war, overextension more than 50%
>   1.0% when: not at war, stability less than +1
>   1.0% when: not at war, war exhaustion more than 10.0
>   1.0% when: not at war, has taken more than 10 loans
>   1.5% when: not at war, legitimacy less than 50
>   2.0% when: not at war, nation is bankrupt
>   **Effects**
>   - +5.00 Unrest
>   - +50% Stability cost modifier
>   - Peasant's War random events.
>   **Ends when**
>   - No revolts are active.
>   - Stability at least +1.

So, the disaster should go away, if your manpower exceeds 25%. If it has already fired, you need to first defeat all revolts, and have a stability of +1.

Source: http://www.eu4wiki.com/Disasters

Comment: @atticae I note that you say that it does not go away. All I can say is, that I had this one and the religious one, and they both went away. I didn't notice if it decreased or disappeared immediatly, but I know I increased my manpower and religious unity.

Comment: I looked at the wiki (see the link in my Q), but it doesn't say what makes the progress bar/disaster disappear again. I will see if 25% manpower really fixes this.

Comment: It's possible that I assumed that if there is no progress, it would decay somehow. I guess just stopping the progress is not enough.

Comment: You are right, the way to cancel a disaster progress is to undo whatever started it. It's not enough to just stop the progress.